# Current Value not loaded for DropDownListFor in ASP.NET Core CSHTML View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I have a field on the screen that I want to restrict the selectable values so I'm using a dropdown built from a dictionary object by a helper to display only valid options.

When first loaded from the DB and displayed the option the code is not translated - Instead it prompts the 'No Option', the first option, not the option on the record.

It works fine once I select a valid option from the dropdown. That new value gets written to the DB on an update.
I just can't get the existing value to translate on the initial load/display. I think I'm missing something in the controller to set it to the current value?

Dictionary:

```
public static class Options
{
    public const string NoOption = "*NONE";
    public const string OptionOne = "OP1";
    public const string OptionTwo = "OP2";
    public const string OptionThree = "OP3";
    public const string OptionFour = "OP4";

    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Values =>
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "No Option", NoOption },
            { "Option One", OptionOne },
            { "Option Two", OptionTwo },
            { "Option Three", OptionThree },
            { "Option Four", OptionFour }
        };
}
```

Model:

```
public string Option { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OptionItems => Options.Values.ToSelectListItem();
```

Helper Extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem(
    this IReadOnlyList<string> values) =>
    from value in values
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = value.ToString(),
        Value = value.ToString()
    };
```

View:

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem.Option, Model.SelectedItem.OptionItems, new { @id = "optionSelection" })
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    selectedItem = itemData.GetItem(SearchTerm);
    if (SelectedItem == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./NotFound");
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Allu, Do you mean the DropDownList displays well, and you want to set the default selected value when page load?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Dropdown is rendered, no problem. But the value in the field does not pick-up it's text translation. instead it always displays the text for the first option in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert dictionary to list

```
var model= new Model{
 OptionItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
}

foreach(var item in Options.Values) {
    model.OptionItems.Add(new SelectListItem {Value= item.Key, Text = item.Value});
}
```

View

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem.Option, 
new SelectList(Model.SelectedItem.OptionItems), new { @id = "optionSelection" })
</div>
```

or better make model like this

```
public string Option { get; set; }

public SelectList OptionItems
```

and move all code here

Comment: Thanks @Serge. That fixed it. I had a bit of a problem with the data on the DB not being trimmed of blanks so I had "OP1 " rather than expected "OP1". But worked great once we sorted that. :-)